# Does preventing the onkeypress event also prevent onchange? Is there a way I can circumvent this?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm using a custom-made mask input that calls `event.preventDefault()` on `keypress`. When I try to add an `onchange` event to it, it simply never fires. It's properly attached, since manually firing `.change()` with jQuery works.

I've removed the `preventDefault` call from the `keypress` handler to test, and `onchange` does indeed fire. Is this behaviour intended? Is there a way I can get around it? I don't think I can do this without preventing default on `keypress`, because there's a whole bunch of condition checking and selection range manipulation that happens after the key gets inserted into the input.

Comment: For me it makes perfect sense. The default behavior of pressing a key in an input is changing its value (except for cursor and modifier keys). I would store the initial value of the input and then, after each `preventDefault()`ed keypress compare the previous value to the current one. If anything changed, I'd fire the change event manually, and update the variable used to track the previous value.

Comment: BTW, have you had a look at [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/#toc-validation)?